# Line break in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I dont know why I cannot make a line break in my javascript. Here is the code:

```
document.write('It\'s ' + n + ',\n'+'SORRY, WE \'RE CLOSED');
```

---

Thanks,

Comment: `document.write('It\'s ' + 42 + ',<br />SORRY, WE \'RE CLOSED');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That function will output HTML, so create line breaks by adding `<br />`, not `\n`.

```
document.write('It\'s ' + n + ',<br />SORRY, WE \'RE CLOSED');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cuLdnjhu/

**However, you shouldn't really be using `document.write()`**:
[Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

A better option is `document.body.innerHTML` or `document.createElement()`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

```html
<span style="white-space:pre">
<script>
var n = 10;
document.write('It\'s ' + n + ',\n'+'SORRY, WE\'RE CLOSED');
</script>
</span>
```